# How do I remove/take back my edit suggestion?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I edited a question that (by my own judgement) needed a more clear statement of what OP wanted. Right now it's *pending review*. But now the OP has edited his own question and it has a completely different context, so now my edit has no relevance to the new question. Is there a way I can withdraw/remove my edit?

Comment: My research skills are so poor, how come I can never find these questions myself? Thank you @ryanyuyu

Comment: Not necessarily what happened here, but a lot of users end up knowing some very cannonical posts and can get back to them easily. Something like this is asked relatively frequently, and ryanyuyu is active on Meta, so there's a good chance you're not the first time he had to look to find that dupe

Comment: It actually took quite a bit of searching.  And it's really only because I knew the answer ahead of time (that it is not possible) that I thought to go dupe hunting.  Don't worry about it too much.  [A certain amount of duplication is good.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) Personally, I think your question title is more easily searchable.

Comment: Pretty reasonable argument @Patrice thanks.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thank you, I marked it already as duplicate

Comment: @edrodriguez which will just make the next time we need to find the dupe target  easier, since I would probably look for this question and follow the dupe-link. Thanks for the sign-post :D

Comment: You're welcome! n_n' @Patrice